# Find subgroups $H$ and $K$ of $G$ such that $H$ is isomorphic to $G$ but $G/H$ is not isomorphic to $G/K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G=\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$,

1). Find subgroups $H$ and $K$ of $G$ such that $H$ is isomorphic to $K$ but $G/H$ is not isomorphic to $G/K$.

2). Find subgroups $A$ and $B$ of $G$ such that $G/A$ is isomorphic to $G/B$ but $A$ is not isomorphic to $B$.

I tried $H$ and $K$ to be $\{(0,0),(0,2)\}$ and $\{(0,0),(1,0)\}$ but I don't know whether $G/H,G/K$ are isomorphic or not. Then I can't find any subgroups that's significantly different. And plus the two subgroups have to have equal size and their quotient groups must also have equal size. I can't see how they could not be isomorphic, or if they could be how I should prove that.

Thanks everyone in advance. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If $H$ is isomorphic to $G$ then $H=G$, and $G/H$ is trivial. Are you sure you don't mean $H$ is isomorphic to $K$?

Comment: Your choice of $H$ and $K$ will work. It's not so hard to compute $G/H$ and $G/K$ from here, either directly or using the First Isomorphism Theorem. Here the quotient groups have to have order $8/2=4$, and there is more than one isomorphism class of groups of order $4$, so that's how they could fail to be isomorphic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of $G$ is eight. In order to have nonisomorphic subgroups or quotients, they would need to be of order four, since there is only one isomorphism class of order one and two, and order eight would imply isomorphic to $G$ itself. The two isomorphism classes of groups of order four are the cyclic group and the Klein four group (i.e. $C_4$ and $C_2\times C_2$). So in the first problem you need to arrange for the isomorphisms $G/H\cong C_2\times C_2$ and $G/K\cong C_4$, both forcing $H$ and $K$ to be of order $2$. In order to check whether you have a solution, you need to be able to compute $G/H$ and $G/K$ (meaning their isomorphism type), which can be done quite easily with the following lemma: if $H_1\le G_1$, $H_2\le G_2$,

$$\frac{G_1\times G_2}{H_1\times H_2}\cong \frac{G_1}{H_1}\times\frac{G_2}{H_2}.$$

For the second problem, all you need to do is exhibit subgroups $H\cong C_4,K\cong C_2\times C_2$.

Comment: I don't get how you can check the isomorphic type with the lemma.

Comment: @verticese Here, the overall group is $G=C_2\times C_4$, so $G_1=C_2$ and $G_2=C_4$. Can you write your subgroups $H$ and $K$ (of $G$) as direct products of subgroups of $C_2$ and $C_4$? Do some work, think about it!