# When do isomorphic group quotients imply isomorphic denominators?

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, quotient-group

This is a general question inspired by a post I read on MSE. Let $A, B, C, D$ be groups, $C, D$ normal subgroups of $A, B$ respectively. If $A \cong B$, $\frac{A}{C} \cong \frac{B}{D}$, what conditions do we need so that $C \cong D$? They can be finite or infinite groups.

We know this isn't true in general, as seen in the second part of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/996086/find-subgroups-h-and-k-of-g-such-that-h-is-isomorphic-to-g-but-g-h-i).

It felt natural to try to use some of the four group isomorphism theorems, but I couldn't seem to make them work in this case.